# Table expand on icon click

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I just want to click on arrow icon (expand_more) to expand not all the line

Code on angular material page:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/oyybnyopyemm?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts

my HTML

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Actions </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-icon (click)="onBlink(element)" class="icon bulb" [ngClass]="element.action ? 'blink_me': ''">wb_incandescent</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon (click)="element.status=!element.status" *ngIf="!element.error" class="icon playPause">{{element.status ? 'play_circle_outline' : 'pause_circle_outline' }}</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="element.error" class="error icon">error</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon *matRowDef="let element">expand_more</mat-icon>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail" >
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
        <div class="example-element-detail"
             [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
          <div>
            <p>Serial : {{element.serial}} </p>
            <p>{{element.name}}have a problem.</p>
            <p>Contact a doctor </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>

    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns;"
        class="example-element-row"
        [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
        (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row" ></tr>
```

can you help me to set it up.

Comment: Hi,, this is working in the demo you shared

Comment: Please share screenshot of issue which you are facing and any console errors. From stackblitz, row expand is working fine

Comment: the link is not my code, it's a demo on material website

Comment: I have setup the expand but I just want to click on the arrow icon to expand, not all the line.

Comment: what does it mean `not all the line`? Just one column should be expanded? Or by clicking your `icon`, then row should be expanded?

Comment: All line(or row) is clickable, i just make the icon clickable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is move the `click` event from the row to your `mat-icon`.

```html
<mat-icon (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element">
    {{expandedElement === element ? 'expand_less' : 'expand_more'}}
</mat-icon>

<!-- ... -->

<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;"
    class="example-element-row"
    [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element">
</tr>
```

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-expandable-mat-table-with-icon).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xgctzj?file=app/table-expandable-rows-example.html) as an example.

What I have done here is basically moved click event handler from row to icon you have added.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-icon (click)="onBlink(element)" class="icon bulb" [ngClass]="element.action ? 'blink_me': ''">wb_incandescent</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon (click)="element.status=!element.status" *ngIf="!element.error" class="icon playPause">{{element.status ? 'play_circle_outline' : 'pause_circle_outline' }}</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="element.error" class="error icon">error</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element">expand_more</mat-icon>
    </td>
</ng-container>
...
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns;"
        class="example-element-row"
        [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element">
</tr>
```

Comment: that does not work , I have nothing after that, just an empty row

Comment: @Sebastian did you just copy pasted code or modified based on your own code? If I understand your question correctly, you want to expand row only when **arrow** is clicked, right?

Comment: @Sebastian what about exaple I have linked. Isn't that working as per what have you asked in the OP?

Comment: no it's the same thing, i tried the same this morning

Comment: @Sebastian what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Sebastian what is the difference between accepted answer and my answer?